# HTML5/CSS layout divs side by side

Tags: html, layout, css

Spend last night (until early morning) hours on fixing this layout issues. I read tons of css3 tips and tricks, but i can't find that what helps me solve this.

See My Fiddle:
[http://jsfiddle.net/aWsmb](http://jsfiddle.net/aWsmb/3/)

Bottom, line: there is a  NAV that needs to be on the left, and a SUBCONTENT that needs to be on the right (classic).  For some reason the SUBCONTENT doesn't want to play and be nice. It either 'shoots' behind the NAV or it sits just next to it, but then it doesn't use all of the width available and overlaps the footer. See fiddle.

This is what i look for:

```
---------------------------------
| header                        |
---------------------------------
| main nav                      |
---------------------------------
| main section                  |
---------------------------------
| NAV | SUBCONTENT (full-widh)  |
|     |                         |
---------------------------------
| footer                        |
---------------------------------
```

Then two additional questions:

```
<div id='subnav'> = better to ASIDE for this?
<div id='association'> = better to use ARTICLE here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of floating the `association` div left, you could just take off the float and give it a `margin-left` the size of the side nav + whatever padding you want. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/aWsmb/15/. That way it'll also fill out it's parent container. Otherwise, if you do use a float, use `overflow: auto` on the parent to ensure the children fill it out.

And yeah if you want to be semantic, use aside for the subnav. I wouldn't worry too much about it though - it's nice to have semantic layouts, but it's not the worst thing you could do :p

Comment: thx! any thought on how to get this table also full width (orange) http://jsfiddle.net/aWsmb/18/ ?

Comment: yeah tried that, i didn't work at first. but it does now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give `float:right` to subcontinent div and you can the give appropriate right margin.
Also to you can remove the `min-height` property of the subcontinent div to avoid the footer overlapping.